# Why does hd-idle need sudo to run in rc.local?

Tags: 14.04, server, sudo, startup-applications

I have added a command that runs "hd-idle". It seems to need to run as root as otherwise it does not spin down the drives as instructed. Behavior seems to be the same when executed manually or via rc.local. hd-idle was compiled with make install as opposed to installed with apt-get if it matters.

From another question on this site I know rc.local runs as root, so why do I still need to add sudo for my hd-idle to run?

Last 2 lines of rc.local:

```
sudo hd-idle -i 300

exit 0;
```

The above rc.local works as expected and the hard drives go into stand by mode after 300 seconds. If I remove "sudo" and reboot the hard drives never spin down.

Comment: What directory did you install the hd-idle program into, and are you giving the full pathname in your rc.local command?

Comment: It's located at /home/media/hd-idle and actually I am not giving it a path just this: sudo hd-idle -i 300  Now I am not sure why it even works at all... When I run it manually with or without sudo I get no errors or any output but with sudo it works as expected.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the actual commands you are running, the line that calls them from the `rc.local`. Also explain what makes you think it fails without `sudo` when run from `rc.local`.

Comment: @terdon question edited, let me know if you need more info.

Comment: OK, that's just weird. rc.local should be run as root. You can try troubleshooting by adding `echo $USER > /tmp/rclog` which will print the user it is running as. Also, make sure that `hd-idle` is in the default path, where is it located?

Comment: Is it possible that somebody configured `sudo` to look in the `/home/media` directory, which is not in root's search PATH when running `rc.local` (so, when `rc.local` attempts to run `hd-idle` without `sudo`, it just gets a "Not found" error, which the user never sees)?

Comment: Ok, I tried adding "echo $USER > /tmp/rclog" to rc.local but the log /tmp/rclog was present yet had no content. The default location for hd-idle is /home/media/hd-idle. I did install hd-idle as "media" user. Here's /etc/passwd line on media user: media:x:1000:1000:Media User,,,:/home/media:/bin/bash Not sure what the triple commas mean.

Comment: @G-Man It's a clean install of ubuntu server 14.04 and I don't think I could have done it by accident. I did install quite a few dependencies to run xbmc gui among other stuff but no one intentionally changed the default path unless i've been hacked or something unlikely like that...

Comment: try a `sudo cp /home/media/hd-idle /bin` then run it from there using the full path (root is owner then)

Comment: @Fabby It is not in /home/media directory. It's installed with make install command, I am not sure where it is stored actually. I checked /bin, /etc and all user home directories but it's not there.

Comment: `locate hd-idle`

Comment: @Fabby 3 locations, 2 of them I removed as they should not exists eg. /mnt/disk4/hd-idle but now even after reboot they show up even though ls -la shows nothing. Is there cache I can clear for locate command to work properly? Install dir seems to be  /usr/local/sbin/hd-idle

Comment: `sudo updatedb` updates the location database (*but* by the time you're reading this, it already has done so automatically)
Does `ll  /usr/local/sbin/hd-idle | awk '{ print $3, $4 }'` show `root root`???  If it does, do you still have the problem?  if it doesn't execute `sudo chown root:root /usr/local/sbin/hd-idle` and report back.

Comment: Yes, it's root:root and no, if I remove sudo and reboot drives do not spin down as before. hd-idle file permissions are fine too -rwxr-xr-x.

Comment: I'm stumped...  Upvoting your question as it's a good one, so it will attract some more knowledgeable people then me...

Comment: Have you searched for the hd-idle app in directories called `sbin`? They contain executables that can only be run by root as far as I know. There must be at least one sbin-directory in `/usr/` or `/usr/share` or `/usr/local/` or anything like this, maybe also directly in `/`. Sitting at a windows pc at the moment, so I can't lok it up. Try google if you don't find it!

Comment: I don't use Ubuntu anymore but will try installing it to test this at some point.

Answer (score 1):

hd-idle requires root to work with the files in /proc/diskstats
 because /proc/ and /dev/ owned by root.

I wouldn't advise changing the ownership, but perhaps you can add your user account to the dial out group.

```
$sudo usermod -a -G dialout <user-name>
```

Then you can try doing things like accessing hardware

You could also try changing the group permissions to /proc/diskstats to include the dialout group. (I am not advising this. but you could try it)

I think some of the logging features write to /var/log/hd-idle
which is also owned by root.

I think you could modify the source, and add a user to the diaout group to get this software to work as a not explicitly root user, but I am recommending caution.

Answer taken from hd-idle source code.

Comment: Will check this out when I have Ubuntu Installed again!